# Webpack image loader not showing any errors when inputting image

Tags: webpack, loader

I using the [image loader](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader) and want to just input an image I have in the same directory as my main.js react component but it's not showing up at all and I'm not getting any errors. I'm using webpack, babel, es6, react, and redux:

**main.js**

```
const Main = () => (
    <div>

      <img src="./pokemon1.png" />
      <SearchableSearchBar />
      <PopulatedProfile />
      <PopulatedTypeHolder />
      <ClickedPokeList />
    </div>
)
```

**webpack config**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/pokeapp'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // js
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
      },
      // CSS
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'

      },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        loaders: [
            'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you try requiring (`require('./pokemon1.png')`) the image? Otherwise webpack can't pick it up. The require will give you something you can put into `src`.

Comment: i tried that and importing in the main.js but it didn't work :l

Comment: Here's the full line `<img src={require('./pokemon1.png')} />`. If that doesn't work, it's hard to say what's going on without having some code to run.